# Playwright multiple fixtures

Tags: typescript, playwright, webautomation

Would it be possible to create new fixture file `myPagesFixture.ts` and add the pages there

`myPagesFixture.ts` :

```
import { test as pagesTest } from '@playwright/test';
import { signupPage } from '../pages/signupPage'
import { addInfoPage } from '../pages/addInfoPage'

type pages = {
    registration: signupPage;
    addInfo: addInfoPage;
}

export const test = pagesTest.extend<pages>({
    registration: async ({ page }, use) => {
        await use(new signupPage(page))
    },

    addInfo: async ({ page }, use) => {
        await use(new addInfoPage(page))
    }
})
```

And then use the basePage.ts file only for importing the other fixtures from different files.
This will later allow us to import test in all spec files only from `basePage.ts`.

`basePage.ts` :

```
import { test as baseTest } from '@playwright/test';
import { test as pagesTest } from './myPagesFixture'


export const test = baseTest.extend({
    ...pagesTest
    // Or something similar in order to expose the elements from the pages?
});

export { expect, Page, BrowserContext } from '@playwright/test';
```

and when importing `test` from `basePage.ts` in the tests to be able to use the elements from the page like this

`registerUser.spec.ts` :

```
import { test } from './fixtures/basePage'

test('register and add info', async ({ registration, addInfo }) => {
   await registration.goToSignupUrl();
   await registration.enterEmail(loginData.adminEmail);
   await registration.enterPassword(loginData.password);
   await registration.clickSignupButton();
   await addInfo.clickAddInfoButton();
   await addInfo.enterName(userData.name);
   await addInfo.enterBirthdate(userData.birthdate);
   await addInfo.clickAddUserInfo();
});
```

I am trying to avoid having the basePage grow bigger and bigger in time. It would be great if I can have all the fixtures in separate files and use the basePage just to expose them to the tests extending `test` from the basePage

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following with your current basePage.ts:

```
import { test as pagesTest } from './myPagesFixture'

export const test = pagesTest
```

As of
[Version 1.39](https://playwright.dev/docs/release-notes#version-139) you can achieve the desired behaviour with the following in your myPagesFixture.ts:

```
import { mergeTests } from '@playwright/test'
import { test as signupPage } from '../pages/signupPage'
import { test as addInfoPage } from '../pages/addInfoPage'

export const test = mergeTests(signupPage, addInfoPage);
```